# Changing NSString from previous UITableviewCell?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I populate a NSMutableArray from a .sqlite database. Inside this array where I grab all the goodies from the database, I run a query to look inside the database. However, I want to be able to change this query dependent on what user selects in UITableview controller prior to this view controller. You'll see the query inside the function:

```
 NSString *character = @"SELECT * FROM strengthexercises WHERE primarymuscle LIKE  '%bicep%'";
    const char *sql = [character cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

That lies within the array method:

```
    -(NSMutableArray *) authorList{
    _theauthors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    @try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StayhealthyExercises.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    }

    NSString *character = @"SELECT * FROM strengthexercises WHERE primarymuscle LIKE '%bicep%'";
    const char *sql = [character cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{

        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            sqlColumns * author = [[sqlColumns alloc] init];
            author.Name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
            author.Muscle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
            author.Description = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 3)];
            author.File= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 4)];
            author.Sets= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 5)];
            author.Reps= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 6)];
            author.Equipment= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 7)];
            author.PrimaryMuscle= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 8)];
            author.SecondaryMuscle= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 9)];
            author.Difficulty= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 10)];

            [_theauthors addObject:author];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return _theauthors;
}
}
```

Now you should see my problem, the query is directly inside the array, I want to be able to control what the query is dependent on what the user selected in the UITableview controller before.

Comment: And when you run it what u get ?
I mean what is the question ? where is the problem ?

Comment: In didSelectRowAtIndexPath (you can know what user selected)
then inside this function you can do whatever you want , extract string from your array and send it to function that will do what needed.

Comment: Please be specific about your problem. It appears that you are trying to change your query text based on the selection of a table cell. But where is the actual issue in that?

Comment: @AyanSengupta Yes your right I want to know how you do what you said could you give me an example?

Comment: @Roma-MT Yes I agree, could you give an example?

Comment: @RobertSaunders you can store your queries to the datasource (possibly a NSArray*) of your table view in form of a format string and once you select a row you can get the string from your datasource and replace the format according to your needs

Comment: @AyanSengupta Yep good idea, but I still need to see an example? Would you mind.

Comment: There is no place here that I can produce an example. If you want help on a specific part of your code, please edit your question and please be specific where you need some help so that we can answer.

Comment: Sure gimme couple of minutes I will make an example for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table view delegate `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` triggers when user  clicks on row in tableView 
assuming you do have a tableView .

inside this function you can "query" what row was selected by switching `indexPath.row`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
  //lest examine the selected row 
  switch(row)
  {
      case 0:
      {
         //call function with string (for 0)
         break;
      }
      case 1:
      {
         //call function with string (for 1)
         break;
      }
      //etc..
  }
}
```

also I assume you do have or can make this function that will lets say get integer and trigger the needed sql query.